# How to colorize an integer in ruby

Tags: ruby

There are a lot of questions on SO about how to colorize ruby output - I saw [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10053836/2128691) first - but they all only change the color of strings.  Is it possible to change the color of other classes?  How could you change `3` to be blue in the console?

Comment: maybe you can try to change the implementation of a `to_s` of Integer. I am not sure this is always used but I think it should work

Comment: i need it to stay an integer, but it's a good thought

Comment: Use [Pry](http://pryrepl.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i use [awesome print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print)
You can set the color classes. also has integration with IRB.

Comment: cool i think this might work - any idea how to colorize conditionally?
for example, `if x = 1, x(color: :blue)`?

Comment: monkey patch this gem!